# Need help in combining two sql queries into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query 1 :

```
SELECT DISTINCT sysnam,COUNT(*) AS High FROM tablename
WHERE Label00002 = '1.High' AND Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT'
GROUP BY sysnam
```

Output:

> SYSNAME,High

```
         A,12

         B,13
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sysnam,count(*) AS Medium FROM tablename
WHERE Label00002 = '2.Medium' AND Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT'
GROUP BY sysnam
```

> Output: SYSNAME,Medium

```
         A,10

         B,11
```

How can I combine both the above queries into one and would like to see the output as below

Output:

> SYSNAME,High,Medium

```
       A,12,10

       B,13,11
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since the GROUP BY produces no duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sysnam, 
       sum(case when Label00002 = '1.High' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
       sum(case when Label00002 = '2.Medium' then 1 else 0 end) as medium
from tablename
where Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT' 
group by sysnam;
```

Note:  It is almost never correct to use `select distinct` when you have a `group by`.

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon, it's working like a charm the way I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join on subselect  based on same sysnam

```
select distinct t1.sysnam,count(t1.*) as High, t2.Medium 
from tablename t1
left join (
    select distinct sysnam,count(*) as Medium from tablename
    where Label00002 = '2.Medium' and Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT'
    group by sysnam
  ) t2 on t2.sysnam = t1.sysnam
where t1.Label00002 = '1.High' 
and t1.Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT'
group by sysnam
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the queries in two CTEs and join the results

```
;with 
cte_qry1 as (
    select distinct sysnam,count(*) as High from tablename
    where Label00002 = '1.High' and Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT'
    group by sysnam
)
cte_qry2 as (
    select distinct sysnam,count(*) as Medium from tablename
    where Label00002 = '2.Medium' and Item_grade = 'NON-COMPLIANT'
    group by sysnam
)
select cte_qry1.sysnam, High, Medium
from cte_qry1
inner join cte_qry2
    on cte_qry1.sysnam = cte_qry2.sysnam
```